# How can I use stored procedures or pivot table selects to manipulate my database data?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, pivot

I have three tables in my database. Users, Applications, and a application_access table which pairs applications with users to represent a user's access to said application.

```
Create table applications (
    id int,
    app_name varchar(45) not null unique,
    app_link varchar(70),
    description varchar(400),
    primary key (id)
);

create table users (
    id int,
    windows_id varchar(25) not null unique,
    full_name varchar(50),
    user_role int,
    email char(50),
    is_active int,
    primary key (id)
);

create table app_access (
    user_id int,
    app_id int,
    app_name varchar(30),
    primary key(user_id, app_id),
    constraint app_fk foreign key (app_id)
    references applications(id),
    constraint user_fk foreign key (user_id)
    references users(id)
);
```

I want to be able to create a select statement that will produce a table that looks like this from my current tables:

Current tables:

[image]

In this data above john has access to both apps while bob only has access to byewrld.

I want a table like this from a sql select statement:

[image]

I could hardcode these values (each application as a column) in my table design but the list of applications and users is growing, and I want to be able to see a user's access to applications as I have shown above.

Comment: To make it flexible you will need ***dynamic** PIVOT*. You may want to start here: https://codingsight.com/pivot-tables-in-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

Try this, So this will show order based on new application is created

```
delimiter $$

create procedure sp_app_user()
begin

select group_concat(concat("sum(if(aa.app_name ='",app_name,"',1,0)) '",app_name,"'")) into @pivotcol
from (select app_name from applications group by app_name order by id) t;

set @pivotquery =concat('select u.id, ',@pivotcol,' from app_access aa 
join users u on aa.user_id=u.id
join applications a on aa.app_id=a.id
group by u.id;');

prepare stmt from @pivotquery;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;

end $$
delimiter ;
```